# Deriving $\cosh^{-1}{x}=\ln\left(x+\sqrt{x^2-1}\right)$

Tags: hyperbolic-functions

Let $y=\cosh^{-1}{x}$. Then, $x=\cosh{y}=\frac{1}{2}\left(e^y+e^{-y}\right)$. Multiplying by $2e^y$, we get $2xe^y=e^{2y}+1$. Solving $e^{2y}-2xe^y+1=0$ by the quadratic formula, we have $e^y=\frac{2x\pm\sqrt{4x^2-4}}{2}=x\pm\sqrt{x^2-1}$. We find that both roots are possible. Thus, $y=\ln\left(x\pm\sqrt{x^2-1}\right)$. Why did we fail to eliminate the minus?

Comment: Because $\operatorname{arccosh}$ is the inverse of _the restriction of $\cosh$ to $[0,+\infty)$,_ so you want $y\geq0$... and since $x-\sqrt{x^2-1}\leq1$, we need to take $x+\sqrt{x^2-1}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why we can dispose of the minus sign is that, firstly, $$(x+\sqrt{x^2-1})^{-1}=(x-\sqrt{x^2-1})$$

Therefore $$\ln(x\pm \sqrt{x^2-1})=\ln(x+\sqrt{x^2-1})^{\pm1}=\pm\ln(x+\sqrt{x^2-1})$$

But $\operatorname{arcosh}(x)$ is defined as non-negative, so the minus sign is not required

Answer (score 1):

The following is a graph of $y=\cosh(x):$

[image]

But the next one is the graph of $y=\operatorname{arccosh}(x)$, considering both real branches$:$

[image]

Applying domain restrictions or branch restrictions, one can remove the $\pm$, but I think the graphs make it clear why one would have the $\pm$ in the first place.

Comment: The graphs remind me of the square root function. It seems conventional to choose the positive output.

Comment: @W.Zhu I must agree, a very classic annoyance.

Answer (score 0):

since the definition of the $$\sqrt{x^2-1}$$ we get $$|x|>1$$ which is for $$x-\sqrt{x^2-1}$$ impossible

Comment: Nop. It is always true that $\;x>\sqrt{x^2-1}\;$ . Perhaps you should read other answers/commetns *before* you post: this already was addressed.

Comment: @DonAntonio No, I think he was pointing out that it must be the case that $x\ge1$, but that still doesn't explain why we would have the $\pm$.

Comment: @SimpleArt Then you were able to understand way more than I was from this cryptic answer...

Comment: @DonAntonio I agree, it doesn't make very much sense :-/

Answer (score 0):

As $y\ge 0$, $\;\mathrm e^y\ge 1$.  Now $\mathrm e^y$ is a root of the quadratic polynomial $\;P(t)=t^2-2xt+1$. Just observe that, as $P(1)=2(1-x) < 0$ for $x>1$, $1$ separates the roots. Hence $\mathrm e^y$ is the greatest root — with a `+` sign.

Comment: If $y\ge0$, since I see nowhere claiming that $y$ must be greater than $0$.

Comment: It's in the definition of $\operatorname{argcosh}$. As $\cosh$ is *not* bijective, we have to consider its *restriction*  to an interval on which it is bijective. One has the choice between  $(-\infty,0]$ andr $[0,+\infty)$. The normal choice has been the second  for centuries. This is the same problem as for the inverse trigonoùetric functions or the square root function.